# Saving data in many to many relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

Please i am new to C# and entity framework, I am working on a projects using web api. I also use postman to test my data and validate them before inserting to database. 
My controller Create will accept a json shown below. The JSON object is mapped to my person model, Assets element of the json is a collection from asset model. what i want to do is retrieve all the asset name in the json and check whether they exist in the asset table. if they exist, get the IDs of the asset and save them all to "PersonAsset" table. 
NOTE that "PersonAsset" contains "PersonID" & "AssetId"

I have spent over 24 hours trying to solve this problem, i need help please

```
    {
  "Id": 0,
  "FirstName": "stringFine",
  "MiddleName": "test-Sesan",
  "LastName": "stringOkay",
  "Gender": "Male",
  "DateOfBirth": "10-10-2017",
  "BirthCertificate": 0,
  "Asset": 0,
  "WorkTypeId": 2,
  "DwellingId": 2,
  "HouseholdRoleId": 2,
  "HealthFacility": 1,
  "Relationship": "string",
  "Education": 0,
  "MaritalStatusId": 2,
  "MobileNumber": "080099813501",
  "SettlementTypeId": 2,
  "CommunityId": 3,
  "SocialGroup": 0,
  "Address": "string",
  "IsInSchool": 0,
  "ReferenceNumber": "100/NSIO/NSR/345660",
  "DateInterviewed": "10-10-2017",
  "IsActive": true,
  "Assets": [
    {
      "Name": "Testing"
    }
  ],
  "SocialGroups": [
    {
      "Name": "string"
    }
  ]
}

   [ResponseType(typeof(PersonModel))]
    [ModelValidator]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Create(PersonModel model)
    {

     try
        {
var person = Factory.Persons.Create(model);
 Service.Persons.Insert(person);
person = Service.Persons.Get(person.Id);
   var dto = Factory.Persons.Create(person);
  return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = dto.Id },dto);
}
catch(dbexception){}
```

How do i accept the values in below JSON and use it in my controller endpoint

```
"Assets": [
    {
      "Name": "Testing"
    }
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your PersonModel look like? See if the code below helps.

Create Asset model

```
public class Asset
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then in PersonModel

```
public class PersonModel
{

    public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Below is my PersonModel Code. Note that i have removed some properties because the class is too long

 namespace nsr.Domain.Model
{

    public class PersonModel 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; 



        public int MaritalStatusId { get; set; }


        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AssetModel>Assets { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SocialGroupModel> SocialGroups { get; set; }
    }